# EXPRESIONES REGULARES PYTHON

Tags: python, regex

como están?

Necesito reconocer direcciones ipv4 usando ER en Python. Estoy usando findall para regresar una lista pero me al muestra vacia [] y hago lo mismo con otra ER más sencilla /d+ y si me regresa la lista. No se que me puede hacer falta para imprimir la lista de ips encontradas. Gracias :D

```
import re

# expresion regular
er = '^(([01]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})|(2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])))(\.(([01]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})|(2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])))){3}$'


# leer el archivo
with open("ips.txt") as archivo:
    contenido = archivo.read()
    # print(contenido)
    found = re.findall(er, contenido)
    print(found)
    #for line in archivo:
    #   print(line)
```

Comment: Está en inglés, pero esta expresión regular te puede servir: [IP address regex python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40370604/1545868)

Comment: Hmmm aun me sigue mostrando la lista vacia [ ], ya probe en regex101 esa expresión y me deja pasar 256.256.256.256.

Comment: como almacena las ip el archivo ips.txt?

Comment: Aisladamente el regex que puse en el primer comentario funciona bien. Tendrás que poner una muestra del archivo ips.txt para ver cómo parsear el archivo de forma correcta.

Comment: 192.168.0.1
1234.2.456.45.65.3
dffrr3

asi esta el archivo txt

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo un archivo de entrada, algo como:

> ips.txt
>
> ```
> 192.168.0.1 1234.2.456.45.65.3 dffrr3 
> 256.0.0.1 192.168.7.2,200.252.8.42 98-7432.89
> 8.8.8.8 -4.4.8.8
> ```

Se podría usar una expresión regular como la siguiente:

```
import re

er = "\\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\b"
with open("ips.txt") as archivo:
    contenido = archivo.read()
    found = re.findall(er, contenido)
    print(found)
```

Resultado: `['192.168.0.1', '192.168.7.2', '200.252.8.42', '8.8.8.8', '4.4.8.8']`

Referencia: [How to extract an IP address from HTML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890896/how-to-extract-an-ip-address-from-an-html-string)